# Проблема в с PDO

Tags: php, mysql

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
> 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL
> server version for the right syntax to
> use near ''10',12' at line 1' in
> /home/www-data/www/test/load.php:25
> Stack trace: #0
> /home/www-data/www/test/load.php(25):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}
> thrown in
> /home/www-data/www/test/load.php on
> line 25

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id,name,year,main_role,description FROM movies ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?,12");
$sql->bindValue("1",$num,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
if ($sql->rowCount() > 0)
{
  while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode(array('status' => 'succes','data' => $data));
}
```

Ребят, подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте:

```
$sql->bindValue("1",(int)$num,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```